# Disabling legacy View Engine compilation mode in Angular 12

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

Since Angular 10, we have had the following set in an angular library:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableIvy": false
}
```

I am now trying to use the Ivy compiler as we upgrade to Angular 12.  From everything I've read, since Ivy is the default, either removing `enableIvy` or setting it to `true` should cause the build to use Ivy.  However, with either of those changes, I still see:

```
Compiling with Angular in legacy View Engine compilation mode.
```

For comparison, I started a new library, and there I see:

```
Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy full compilation mode.
```

I can't figure out what else is different that is causing Angular to still use View Engine.  What else should I be looking for?

Comment: A library is dealt with slightly different I think. You should build it without the —prod flag if I remember correctly..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the problem with Angular 12 and packagr and solved it in two steps:

1. Enable ivy in the tsconfig.json:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableIvy": true,
  "compilationMode": "partial"
}
```

The `compilationMode` is relevant, when you want to publish your lib to any npm registry.

2. Ensure, that the compiler sees and **uses** *this* tsconfig.json.
   It seems to me that the cli parameter for the config is madatory in Angular 12.
   I updated my *scripts* in package.json:

```
"packagr": "ng-packagr -p ./src/lib/package.json -c ./src/tsconfig.json"
```

The `-c` (or `--config`) part is missing in most examples.